# Making text bold in java

Tags: java, text

I was working on some of my project and i faced this problem,i want to print name in bold and txt as plain.
Here TF1 and TF2 are JTextFields.
TA1 is JTextArea.
I will glad if you help me out.
Thanks!

```
String name=TF1.getText();
String txt=TF2.getText();
TA1.append(name+":"+txt+"\n");
```

Comment: `JTextArea` is not able to change the font for individual parts of the string. You need to use some other component. In Java some Components support HTML formatting like `JLable` or `JEditorPane`.

Comment: If you have to use a JTextArea, you could use unicode as a *hack*. Unicode has code points for [bold, italic, ... versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) of the alphabet. You just need to write a function that converts a part of your string to its bold equivalent.